# How to open existing Excel file using TCL?

Tags: excel, file, tcl

I have a question to open an existing Excel file with Tcl. In this case, I do not want to get datas from the file but I want to call the Excel file and open it directly.

Does anyone know how to open an existing Excel file with Tcl Tk, and make it stay open?

Comment: Can you provide a snipptet of your code/ what you already tried?

Comment: I tried to make it and search for the command many times. However I found only the way to open file to get data. Now, it works. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing to try is this:

```
# For convenience only, put the filename in a variable
set theExcelFile "FooBar.xlsx"

# Ask the OS to mimic a double-click on the file
exec {*}[auto_execok start] "" [file nativename [file normalize $theExcelFile]]
```

It will work with any file type registered with Windows.

Comment: @user3397873: If the answer was helpful for you, you might consider clicking the check mark to accept the answer. That makes it more clear to people browsing the site that the answer is useful.