# tcl exec to open a program with agruments

Tags: command-line, tcl, exec

I want to open a text file in notepad++ in a particular line number. If I do this in cmdline the command should be:

```
start notepad++ "F:\Path\test.txt" -n100
```

And it is working fine from command line. Now I have to do this from tcl. But I can't make this command work with **exec**. When I try to execute this:

```
exec "start notepad++ \"F:\Path\test.txt\" -n100"
```

I am getting this error:

```
couldn't execute "start notepad++ "F:\Path\test.txt" -n100": no such file or directory.
```

What am I missing. Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22279632/1578604):

```
exec {*}[auto_execok start] notepad++ F:/Path/test.txt -n10
```

First, you need to supply each argument of the command as separate values, instead of a single string/list. Next, to mimic the `start` command, you would need to use `{*}[auto_execok start]`.

I also used forward slashes instead of backslashes, since you would get a first level substitution and get `F:Path  est.txt`.

---

EDIT: It escaped me that you could keep the backslashes if you used braces to prevent substitution:

```
exec {*}[auto_execok start] notepad++ {F:\Path\test.txt} -n10
```

Comment: Not all windows programs or programs written for windows will accept the / in an argument.

Comment: @BradLanam Ok... do you know what should one do if one has a specific path like in the OP so that the argument will be accepted in windows no matter the program?

Comment: As in your reference question, using `[file nativename "F:/Path/test.txt"]` should work just fine.  Your answer is good.

Comment: @BradLanam Ah thanks. Hmm, that means we could also pass `[file nativename {F:\Path\test.txt}]` instead, if the initial path is typed in backslashes for some reason.

Comment: `file nativename` changes `/` to backslash on Windows; that's all it does now that Mac OS 9 is no longer a concern. (Classic Mac filenames were… different…)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply surround the entire exec statement in curly braces. Like this:

```
catch {exec start notepad++.exe f:\Path\test.txt -n10}
```

Comment: I've added the catch out of a habit... After omitting the 'start' it works. I use it in my application and it's OK (Tcl8.5 @ Windows7 64-Bit)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a perfect solution to this yet.  All my execs seem to be different from each other.  On windows there are various issues.

- Preserving double quotes around filename (or other) arguments.

  - e.g. in `tasklist /fi "pid eq 2060" /nh` the quotes are required.
- Preserving spaces in filename arguments.
- Preserving backslash characters in filename arguments.
  [Internally, Windows doesn't care whether pathnames have / or \, but some programs will parse the filename arguments and expect the backslash character].

The following will handle the backslashes and preserve spaces, but will not handle double-quoted arguments.  This method is easy to use.  You can build up the command line using list and lappend.

```
set cmd [list notepad]
set fn "C:\\test 1.txt"
lappend cmd $fn
exec {*}$cmd
```

Using a string variable rather than a list allows preservation of quoted arguments:

```
set cmd [auto_execok start]
append cmd " notepad"
append cmd " \"C:\\test 1.txt\""
exec {*}$cmd
```

Note that if you need to supply the full path to the command to be executed, it often needs to be quoted also due to spaces in the pathname:

```
set cmd "\"C:\\Program Files\\mystuff\\my stuff.exe\" "
```